# Remover elemento html criado de forma dinâmica no success do ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Criei uma requisição ajax para no sucesso criar, de forma dinâmica, um novo elemento **li**, no entanto tenho uma função também em ajax para eliminar o registo e no sucesso eliminar o **li** criado.
O problema está que, em todos os elementos que foram criados dinamicamente, apenas deixa apagar esses elementos se fizer um refresh à página.
Gostava de conseguir apagar esses elementos criados dinamicamente sem ter de fazer refresh à página.

Seguem o exemplo:

HTML:

```
<ul class="collection with-header">
        <li class="collection-header">
            <h4>Ramos <a href="#addRamo" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">library_add</i></a></h4>
        </li>
                                            <li class="collection-item" ramoli="1">
                    <div>Especialização em Tecnologias
                        <input name="ramos[]" type="hidden" value="1">
                        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0)" ramo="1" class="deleteRamo secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                                <li class="collection-item" ramoli="2">
                    <div>Especialização em Cultura e Artes
                        <input name="ramos[]" type="hidden" value="2">
                        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0)" ramo="2" class="deleteRamo secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                                <li class="collection-item" ramoli="3">
                    <div>Especialização em Música Interactiva e Design de Som
                        <input name="ramos[]" type="hidden" value="3">
                        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0)" ramo="3" class="deleteRamo secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                                <li class="collection-item" ramoli="4">
                    <div>Especialização em Educação
                        <input name="ramos[]" type="hidden" value="4">
                        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0)" ramo="4" class="deleteRamo secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>


                    <li class="collection-item">
                        <div>Registo dinamico
                            <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                            <a href="javascript: void(0)" ramo="38" class="deleteRamo secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
                        </div>
                </li></ul>
```

Função em ajax para criar registo:

```
$( "#btnAddRamo" ).on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/config/ramos',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#formAddRamo').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( _response ){
                $("#collection-ramos ul").append(`
                    <li class="collection-item">
                        <div>${_response.data.name}
                            <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                            <a href="javascript: void(0)" ramo="${_response.data.id}" class="deleteRamo secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
                        </div>
                </li>`);
                Materialize.toast(_response.message, 4000);
            },
            error: function( _response ){
                // Handle error
            }
        });
    });
```

Função ajax para apagar registo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteRamo',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let idRamo = jQuery(this).attr('ramo');
        let element = $(`li[ramoLi=${idRamo}]`);

        let currentToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            url: `/admin/config/ramos/${idRamo}`,
            type: 'DELETE',
            data: {_token:currentToken},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( _response ){
                $(element).remove();
                Materialize.toast(_response.message, 4000);
            },
            error: function( _response ){
                Materialize.toast(_response.message, 4000);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Mas, aonde tu tem a propriedade: `ramoLi`, que tu obtém aqui: `$('li[ramoLi=${idRamo}]');`?

Comment: Queres apagar o mesmo que inseriste com ajax certo?

Comment: Sim, ele apaga os que existem se a pagina tiver sido carregada, mas não paga os que foram criados entretanto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para apagar o `'.collection-item'` clicado basta procurares por `$(element).closest('.collection-item').remove();`, onde `element` é o `this`. Ou seja:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteRamo',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const idRamo = jQuery(this).attr('ramo');
    const element = this;

    const currentToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajax({
        url: `/admin/config/ramos/${idRamo}`,
        type: 'DELETE',
        data: {_token:currentToken},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( _response ){
            $(element).closest('.collection-item').remove();
            Materialize.toast(_response.message, 4000);
        },
        error: function( _response ){
            Materialize.toast(_response.message, 4000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfeito :D obrigado